# Select and count for each record in one query

Tags: mysql, sorting, count

I have to database tables: "users" and "results". I want to browse users from table users and count specific records of each individual users in table results (to count games played and wins). My query:

```
$q = "SELECT *, (SELECT count(*)  
                 FROM users, results 
                 WHERE (results.u1 = users.id OR results.u2 = users.id) 
                 AND (results.p1 > 0 OR results.p2 > 0) 
                 AND gid = '$gid' AND users.gender = '$gender') as gp 
      FROM users LEFT JOIN results 
                               ON users.id = results.u1 
                                           || 
                                  users.id = results.u2 
      WHERE gid = '$gid' AND users.gender = '$gender' 
      GROUP BY users.id LIMIT 0, 9";
```

This does return 9 users but "gp" shows me count of all records, but I want gp part to count only records for each individual user in the loop and ORDER by it.

Can you help me with this query? THank you!

Comment: Please add the struture of the two tables and explain the role of some of the key columns, then add some sample and expected data.

Comment: Can you add a db-fiddle with your tables and some data, so we can test: https://dbfiddle.uk/ (once created, just post the fiddle link with full address)

Comment: Table users contains: id, gender. 
Table results contains: u1 (user one id), u2(user two id), p1 (points of user 1), p2 (points of user 2).
Lats say results have 3 records. I want to check if table results has user table id in column u1 or u2. If I find user id in result columns I want to count only that column, not all the others. Current query counts all record at once - but  I want to count number of found record for each user individually.

Answer (score 0):

select user id and create its Alias and use it in your subquery

```
select user_id as userid  (select  count(*) from result where results.u2 = userid) as result_count  from users ;
```